# Is the phrase "over the years", used in the correct place in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, syntax

This has been as consistent as the sun coming up over the years.

Answer (score 1):

"over the years" is used in the correct place, yes, but a native speaker might think this sentence sounds weird. As a native speaker, I would probably say:

> This *is* as consistent as the sun *rising*.

Since the sun has been around for millions of years, many English speakers associate qualities of the sun with longer periods of time such as decades or centuries, not merely over the span of a few years. You'd sound a bit more natural if you omitted 'sun' and simply stated:

> This has been consistent over the years.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. However, I intend to use "over the years" not for the sun for obvious reasons, but for "this". This has been consistent over the years as the sun coming up. Does this sound natural?

Comment: I understand that. In the sentence I provided you with, "over the years" is being applied to the time period for which "this" has been consistent, it does not apply to the sun. Do you have to use the sun as an example? Because if not, I would leave it as "This has been consistent over the years". It sounds more natural. If you do, then saying "This is as consistent as the sun rises " sounds more natural. You don't need "over the years".